# Zero Gravity Evolution in People part 2

Tags: evolution, science-fiction, gravity

While gravity is a constant force, is it possible for an animal to evolve within a low gravity environment to walk along the ground? Yes or no and if yes how?

Thanks folks!

Comment: Far to broad. What kind of animal? What kind of ground? Is it rough or smooth? Is there an atmpsphere or are we talking deep space? Are we talking 0 gravity or merely very low gravity? Does the animal have ancestry on Earth or did it fully evolve in this 0 gravity environment? We need details.

Comment: This is too broad, as Mormacil pointed out. Also, what's up with the title? The title should summarize the question you are asking; even in these few sentences, you manage to confuse "zero" and "low" gravity, and "people" and "animals".

Comment: Looking at your profile I can see that you intend to make some sort of series of questions like this. That's fine. In fact it's pretty good, as many people tend to start with too broad questions that need to narrowed down and split into multiple people. But remember that each question should be able to stand on it's own. And even if it's not a strict requirement the title often is in the form of a question as this is a Q&A. Furthermore this question needs more information so that we can help you with your questions. You can link to older questions in a "Further information:" style. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Geckos can walk up walls, glass, on ceilings, etc due to Van der Waals forces:
See http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2002/08/how-geckos-stick-der-waals

These are not gravity, or glue, or secretions; it is inter-molecular forces; and in fact are strong enough to counter-act Earth gravity for a relatively heavy creature.

The same could apply to creatures in a weightless environment; and there is good reason for that to be done. Although "swimming" through air is an option (birds and insects do it), it takes a lot of energy. Being able to stick to a surface is useful. Being able to walk on one; like a gecko, could be useful too. Static electricity often causes floating objects to stick to surfaces; and some of these have calories. So surfaces may be where small insects alight to hunt for those calories; and being able to wait for such insects without expending any energy and eat them is a useful adaptation.

I'm not sure what your goal is; but the Van der Waals forces that can keep a gecko upside down on the ceiling have been, in experiments, scaled up to hold 200 lb men on the ceiling, and that is against **Earth** gravity. Presumably it would be pretty easy, in a weightless environment, to stick to any surface if normal sized human feet and/or hands had evolved the tiny gecko hairs that allow geckos to stick to surfaces.

The writing job is to find a plausible reason for walking such surfaces; but I think you (the OP) already have something in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The less gravity there is the leaner/lankier the creature's build will be. Theorized is that if a human would grow up on the moon that person would be taller than average. So sure, your creature could walk on a rocky surface in a low gravity environment, but low gravity environments also have trouble sustaining an atmosphere which in itself is a massive issue for what you want.

As for the creature's build, lean, lanky, long legs with long but lean muscles to facilitate the movement.

Answer (score 0):

If by low gravity you mean zero gravity as in space - then the answer would be no.  There would be no evolutionary pressure to develop that ability - and lots of pressure to develop other methods of locomotion.

If by low gravity you mean something like the Moons Gravity - then yes. So long as atmosphere existed that supports life then evolutionary pressure would likely develop the ability to walk along the ground in that low gravity environment.  BUT put a creature that had evolved on a planet with 1 sixth the gravity of earth (EG the moon) into a 1 G environment - like earth - and they would be prostrate on the ground.

There was a recent movie on this exact topic: [The Space Between Us](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3922818/)  While it wasn't as dramatic as if the boy had grown up on the moon - it was still a clear example of what is likely to happen when somebody whose species evolved in a 1 G environment is born and raised on a planet with a little over 1/3 of the gravity of Earth.  The effect would be far more pronounced on a species that EVOLVES on a low G planet...